# How to use a default value when using util.Interpolate

Tags: buildbot

I'm using something like `util.Interpolate('%(src::branch)s')` to get the name of the branch from my Subversion repository. This works as expected when polling the repository but not when forcing a build.
Is it possible to somehow use `util.Interpolate('%(src::branch)s')` so that when the branch is None or an empty string it uses "trunk" instead?

`util.Interpolate('%(src::branch)s')` should return the `src::branch` property when one has been set or else `trunk`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [buildbot docs](http://docs.buildbot.net/current/manual/configuration/properties.html#interpolate) it should be:

`util.Interpolate('%(src::branch:-trunk)s')`

> The following ways of interpreting the value are available:
>
> -replacement
>
> If the key exists, substitute its value; otherwise, substitute
> replacement. replacement may be empty (default), %(prop:propname:-)s.
>
> ~replacement
>
> Like -replacement, but only substitutes the value of the key if it is
> something Python regards as True. Python considers None, 0, empty
> lists, and the empty string to be false, so such values will be
> replaced by replacement.
>
> +replacement
>
> If the key exists, substitute replacement; otherwise, substitute an
> empty string.